# Clarification of one-way property of hash functions

Tags: hash, one-way-function

> One-way property: computationally infeasible to find data mapping to
>   specific hash

The definition above is a little vague, if we have h(x) = `floor(log(x))`, finding "some" *x* that gives a hash value is easy, however, deterministically finding the actual *x* value that has led to the output is impossible. Do such hash functions have the one-way property?

Comment: The definition you quote is more than a little vague. You will find correct definitions in any good crypto textbook.

Comment: You mean, Pre-image resistance :  computationally infeasible to find the reverse image of a given hash value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find “some” value, mapping to a specific hash, that would mean it’s not really a one-way hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is too easy. Given an hash value $h$, calculate $b^h$ and $b^{h+1}-1$, where b is the base of your logarithm.

Any value between $b^h$ and $b^{h+1}-1$ will be pre-image.

Comment: Yes. Thus $x\to h(x)=\left\lfloor\log_b(x)\right\rfloor$ is not one way, because it is computationally feasible to find data mapping to a specific hash. The question's definition is correct, if a little imprecise.

Comment: Yes, it is easy. I just wanted to give an example of something that is reversible, but not uniquely. The question is if the attacker is lost among a large number of candidates, is it still a one-way function?

Comment: He is no lost, all of the values are correct in the sense of the attacker, even for you. Think about the usual hash based password protection. All of the pre-images are valid passwords to login.